# How to convert String Format data

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Json format like:

```
 var d =  "1,3,2,4"
```

How do I convert it into

```
 var d =   [3,5,3,6]
```

I tried this:

```
success: function (Response) {
    debugger;
    var du = (Response.d);
    var final_string = '[' + du + ']'
    // final_string = [1, 3, 2, 4];
    console.log(final_string);
```

But this is not working, I want to `final_string` value as  `final_string = [1, 3, 2, 4];`

actually i am trying to making a graph by this data

JvaScript

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "Default.aspx/getdata",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (Response) {
                    debugger;
                    var d = Response.d.toString();
                    var final_string = '[' + d + ']'
                    console.log(final_string);
                    //final_string = [1,3,2,4];
         var options = {
             chart: {
                 height: 250,
                 width:500,
                 type: 'line',
             },
             series: [{
                 name: ' ',
                 type: 'column',
                 data: final_string
             }, {
                 name: '',
                 type: 'line',
                 data: final_string
             }],
             stroke: {

                 width: [0, 4]
             },
             title: {
                 text: 'Total Count'
             },
             labels: ['Birthady', 'Anniversary', 'Special', 'Total'],
             xaxis: {
                 type: 'text'
             },
             yaxis: [{
                 title: {
                     text: 'Count Blog',
                 },
             }, {
                 opposite: true,
                 title: {
                     text: ''
                 }
             }]
         }
         debugger;
         var chart = new ApexCharts(
             document.querySelector("#chart"),
                      options

                    );

                    chart.render();

                },
                error: function (result) {
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

here the series data format is `[1,3,2,4]` and when i am passing `data = [1,3,2,4]` in series data graph is display in correct format and when i am passing `final_string` in series data graph is not display in correct format what is the main issue in this format `final_string` can any one help me
 ?

Comment: `d.split(',')` ?

Comment: What does the first `d` have to do with the second, except for the number of characters between the commas?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `split(",")` function. Since you're using the array on a chart you can use `map(Number)` to convert each item of the array to a **Number** type instead of a **String**.

```js
var d =  "1,3,2,4"
var res = d.split(",").map(Number);

console.log(res)
```

I based my **response** on the example in: [ApexCharts](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/column-charts/column-with-data-labels/)

You need an array of Numbers like:

```
[2.3, 3.1, 4.0, 10.1, 4.0, 3.6, 3.2, 2.3, 1.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2]
```

Comment: can you check my edited question please

Comment: I have updated my answer. What you need is an array of numbers and not a string like you seem to be using on "final_string"

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (Response) {
    debugger;
    var d = Response.toString();
    var final_string = '[' + d + ']'
    console.log(final_string);
}
```

Comment: can you check my edited question please